# Book tagging with mongodb (many-to-many) implementation

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Im trying to build a simple application in python, where I have tags that I associated to tags.

Given the following data:

Book:

```
+-------------+--------------------------------+
|     id      |             tags               |
+-------------+--------------------------------+
|      1      |     [python, ruby, rails]      |
+-------------+--------------------------------+
|      2      |     [fiction, fantasy]         |
+-------------+--------------------------------+
|      3      |     [fiction, adventure]       |
+-------------+--------------------------------+
```

How would I (using pymongo) find:

1. All books tagged as "fiction"
2. All unique tags in the system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Find all books by tag:

```
db.books.find({tags: 'ruby'})
```

This will be faster if you index the field.

```
db.books.ensureIndex({tags: 1})
```

#### 2. Find all unique tags

You can use map-reduce

```
var map = function() {
  this.tags.forEach(function(t) {
    emit(t, 1);
  })
};

var reduce = function(k, vals) {
  return {k, 1}
};

db.books.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: 'temp_collection_name'});
```

All examples are in javascript, they should work right away in mongo shell. I leave it to you to read the pymongo docs and translate the snippets.

Comment: why mapreduce? why not db.books.distinct("tags")?

Comment: `distinct` will fail if there are too many tags (more than document limit).

Comment: more than a million and a half tags?